# WFS layer not showing all data in ArcGIS Pro or not showing at all in QGIS, and inconsistent preview

Tags: geoserver, wfs, oracle-spatial

I have a layer in GeoServer that is pulled in from Oracle. WMS shows all data as expected. WFS exhibits these problems.

1. ArcGIS Pro, only a subset of the data is shown
2. QGIS, the layer is loaded, but shows no data, in the QGIS layers box there is no tick to turn layer on/off
3. Using layer preview in GeoServer I download the layer as KML/SHP, and it only downloads a small subset, but a different subset to the one shows in 1.

This happens with three of my layers I pull in from Oracle. Other layers from local shapefile storage in the workspace are fine.

The dataset didn't t have a primary key in Oracle, but I've added one, and has 29893 records.

The URL used the server connection is server:8080/geoserver/ows?

The server is intranet only and not publicly available.

ArcGIS Pro returns exactly 3000 records, so that may indicate a limit somewhere? The log file from the Arc request gives a warning:
There's a namespace parameter but it seems it wasn't parsed to a org.xml.sax.helpers.NamespaceSupport: xmlns(m20721=urn:x-test:M20721)

QGIS shows zero records, but in the info gives the record count as 29893. The log file shows several Java errors:
21 Dec 10:08:16 ERROR  [geoserver.ows] -
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException
then a long list of at...
and also:
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot do natural order without a primary key, please add it or specify a manual sort over existing attributes

Any ideas what I need to change in the settings?

Comment: 1) do you have a primary key 2) what is the full URL of the request being made in the requests in each case. Please [edit] your question with these details and any relevant information in the log file

Comment: How many features are there in the dataset?

Comment: There are 29893 features in the dataset

Comment: So I added a PK and, after reloading the feature type, QGIS shows all records. ArcGIS Pro still only shows 3000. Two problems solved, thanks, one to go.

Comment: See the ArcGIS documentation... by default it fetches only 3000 features: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/services/add-wfs-services.htm

Answer (score 1):

The preview is limited to 50 features, to avoid killing the browsers that tried to pretty-print the XML/JSON.

WFS itself has a feature limit, by default pretty high, 10,000,000, which controls how many features are returned in a single request. WFS 1.1 and WFS 2.0 support paging, a proper client should be able to use it and get the full dataset.

You can change both limits in the WFS configuration:
https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/webadmin.html#features

Comment: That's sorted the preview issue, thanks for clarifying. It's unrelated to the data issue in Arc and QGIS, that's still an issue.

Answer (score 0):

To summarise:

1. Needed to set MAXFEATURES in the custom request parameters of the ArcGIS Pro connection (after solving 2)
2. The Oracle spatial layer needed a primary key, and after adding one the Feature types needed reloading in the layer settings on GeoServer.
3. The feature limit needed to be changed in the WFS config