GeoServer - vector layer features clipped to only 50 features when downloading
Whenever publishing vector layers in GeoServer, and I download the layer in ANY format, whether shapefile, CSV, etc, I  get a product with 50 features only. This applies to points, lines, and polygons - any vector geometry. I set the Per-Request Feature Limit in the publishing tab to one million with no change. How do I correct this so that all features in a layer are downloaded?

How exactly are you downloading?

Sounds like you are using the preview page links that are limited to 50 features to avoid overwhelming browsers. Remove the feature count from the URL

see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/447993/wfs-layer-not-showing-all-data-in-arcgis-pro-or-not-showing-at-all-in-qgis-and/448061?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C40.1648#448061

Answer was given by Ian Turton. Go to the WFS settings page and under Features, change the value in "Maximum number of features for preview (Values <= 0 use the maximum number of features)"
